# Geolocation runs when swapping tabs inside Tracker.autorun

Tags: meteor

This is my code on client using [geolocation api](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/tree/master/packages/mdg:geolocation)

```
Tracker.autorun(function () {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {

        // Runs every time i come back on the tab.
        console.log(Geolocation.latLng());
    }
});
```

I only want this code to run when the user logs in so I get the users location. But this code runs every time when i go to a different tab and back to the same tab.
Is this a bug or the Geolocation html5 API just works this way. Because when i remove `console.log(Geolocation.latLng());` Deps.autorun doesnt run every time coming back to the tab.

Comment: With Meteor 1.0 you should be using `Tracker.autorun` instead of `Deps.autorun` (they renamed the package). Also I am not sure if the browser sends their location every time you click on the tab perhaps, which would explain why Meteor thinks the location has changed (even if just by a minute or second). I'd guess it does, given what you describe.

Comment: Thank you for the `Tracker.autorun`. Will dfntly change it now.